# How to prevent multiple html selection box displayed on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been working on the last bit of my php + ajax based datagrid project.Everything works as I designed except one thing : I cannot stop user opening multiple selection boxes...

> Go [my research page](http://chenximao.net/webscraper/) and use username "ChenxiMao" and password "accedo" to login(without double quotes).

Note that perhaps the images used in this datagrid would not be displayed when page is loaded for the first time(weird, I am trying to fix this, browser incompatibilities, perhaps).

If you double click on one cell in the "CONSULTANT" column, a html select box would be displayed, you can select one consultant to assign him to this task or unassign the consultant from this task. No problem for this.

The problem is : when user leaves this selection box OPEN, he/she can still open another selection box... My jquery code cannot stop people from opening multiple selection boxes.

You can ctrl-U to see the source code on this page, and check the content inside the "gridview-helper.js" for what I have been done.

I want to let user only open a single selection box. When he/she leaves the cell, the selection box should be closed, without changing the html inside...

Puzzled, screwed up for this afternoon...

Thanks for any suggestons in advance!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is single-threaded, so you can add a mutex variable and check its value before opening a new select box.

At the top of `gridview-helper.js`:

```
var is_choice_visible = false;
```

In your double-click handler:

```
$(this).dblclick(function()
{
    if (is_choice_visible)
        return;
    is_choice_visible = true;
...
```

For your select box, add an `onblur` handler which sets `is_choice_visible` back to `false` and deletes itself.

**Unrelated tip:** Growing a string in a loop is slow on older versions of Internet Explorer. It's more efficient to append to an array and join the array, e.g.:

```
var html = ["<select>..."];
for (var i in consultantnames)
{
    html.push("<option>...</option>");
}
html.push("</select>");
return html.join("");
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip!

I will try working it out following your way!

Comment: var htmlStr = "<select class='select_consultant'onChange='assignConsultant("+ id + ")');'><option selected='true'>choose a consultant</option>";

Line 54 doesn't like another event to be added... I tried to add the onBlur event to it but failed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but I rechecked your source and noticed that you're missing a space before "onchange."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `onmouseout` event on the cell, and removing the child dropdown box element if mouse out is triggered?  Seems that should work.

Comment: Tried, but failed... that would cause a infinite loop and I cannot remove the selection box... Maybe I did it wrong...